# SSL/TLS renegotiation for older jvm without critical fix RFC-5746

Tags: java, security, ssl

I have a system that uses Java 5 and Java 6 but with a version that have not implemented the fix from Oracle RFC-5746.

I the future I will update the Java version to overcome this problem but meanwhile I want to do something to overcome this problem.

I have read the documentation and a lot of forums but I have not seen a good workaround for this issue.

Comment: Do you use renegotiation? If no, then there's no need for a fix.

Comment: Yes I use renegotiation.

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp There is a need for a fix,  attackers use renegotiation to perform a DoS.  You should do more research.

Comment: @AlexGo you could look for an alternative TLS/SSL implementation in java.  I wouldn't hold your breath for a fix from Oracle,  they have a terrible security track record.  Also this is a "high"  vulnerability that is exploited in the wild and needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Rook Have a link to read? Though I must mention that attackers use plenty of different things to arrange a DoS

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp yeah but,  tls renegotiation is a 30+ cpu multiple,  an android phone could take down a 16 core opteron,  no problem.  You don't even need a botnet.